# how can take row number 10 to 20 over 100+ rows using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

i have a table with 100+ rows ,i want to row number  10 to 20 using entity frame work ,but i can't understand how to write the code

my code is

```
 db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Take(10, 20).ToList());
```

but it showing error

Comment: Show us the error.

Comment: You were close: db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList());

Comment: Have you tried `db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();`?

Comment: Always use `OrderBy`  with paging. Otherwise it's arbitrary and unpredictable what you will get.

Comment: please write full query using **orderby** @TimSchmelter

Comment: @SkAsraf: `db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Skip(10).Take(10)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter when i use your code then product first 10 row but when i write this query **db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();** it work as aspected.

Comment: thanke @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.Skip()` and `Take()`

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

^*Also the error is Extra `)` at the end.*

**[Note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941013/how-can-take-row-number-10-to-20-over-100-rows-using-entity-framework/37941050#comment63331080_37941013)** *(Suggested by *Tim Schmelter* & *MatBailie*) : Order your resultset before paging the rows to avoid arbitrary and unpredictable output.

Comment: Just as I'd posted the same in the comments! Spot on.

Comment: @GeoffJames, right. But the actual issue - the error as explained by OP is extra `)` at the end. :)

Comment: Thanks @Shaunak, just spotted that - Copy/pasting quickly is a dangerous thing at times!

Comment: As per a comment on the OP, surely you need to order the set before skipping 10 and taking the next 10?  *(If this generates SQL without an ORDER BY, the 10 rows you get are arbitrary, and while they're unlikely to vary, they might.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, true! I'll add that as a suggestion.

Comment: yes it showing error like.**The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'**

Comment: the exact query should be `db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();` orderBy is needed.

Comment: @SkAsraf: but you notice that this query is pointless? You are filtering by a `ProductName`, then you are ordering by name. So you either get only one record, then ordering and paging would be pointless or you get many records with this `ProductName`, then the `OrderBy` would be redundant because all rows had the same name and you'd again get arbitrary rows. Note that you can also append `...ThenBy(p => p.OtherColumn)` after `OrderBy` to order by multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Skip method:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: orderBy is need the code will be `db.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "product").OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();`